# redux-form fire action change value but not change input value

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm using simple form by redux-form. I can see the log which fire action which change the field however it the change is not displayed in input field itself. Seems redux-form is not able to change input value. I'm using React version 16.3.

#### [Update]

I'm using [exact sample](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/simple/) redux-form document.

Comment: Please add the relevant code

Comment: please post the code here to answer

Answer (score 2):

I suscpect that You didn't connect redux-form with store. I had one same issue. This code is important.

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  // ...your other reducers here
  // you have to pass formReducer under 'form' key,
  // for custom keys look up the docs for 'getFormState'
  form: formReducer
})

const store = createStore(rootReducer)
```